# Scala: preferred way to override a method that takes an implicit argument?

Tags: scala, implicit

Given the method, e.g.,

```
def delayed(howlong: Duration)(implicit timer: Timer): Future[A]
```

What is the *preferred* way to override it, keeping the implicit implicit, or making it explicit?

*And* does it matter, or is does keeping it implicit just de-sugar to explicit?

```
override def delayed(howlong: Duration)(implicit timer: Timer): Future[A] 
   = super.delayed(howlong)
```

OR

```
override def delayed(howlong: Duration)(implicit timer: Timer): Future[A] 
   = super.delayed(howlong)(timer)
```

(Note, I know my example overrides do nothing; I'm just trying keep the question simple. Imagine I'm adding a log statement.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not really about how to override the method, it is about how to call the `super` implementation of the method when the method has `implicit` parameters. There is also an element of opinion here, so this is just my view:

You should treat it like a call to any other function with `implicit` parameters. That is, you omit the `implicit` argument unless there is a specific reason for specifying it. The main reason to specify an `implicit` value is that there is no suitable value in scope and it is simpler than creating a new `implicit val` for a single call. If the appropriate `implicit val` is already in scope I cannot see any good reason to pass it explicitly.

So in your specific case I would pass the `timer` implicitly.